# Accepting duplicating records and notifying user about duplicate record

Tags: trigger, validation, leads, professional-edition, duplicate-management

We are using Professional licence for our org and the salesforce system is integrated with a marketing automation tool so that leads will enter to salesforce through the Marketing tool.

A single person may fill different forms any times but client needs all submissions must be generated as a lead in salesforce. For this I have deactivated Duplicate rules , but user also want to know that if any lead enter to the system for the second time they must identify  that there is a record exist with same mobile number or email, I suppose this can be possible using a trigger but in Professional licence , I have no access to code. Please let me know if there is any possibility for this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The standard out of the box **[Duplicate Management](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=managing_duplicates_overview.htm)** tool supports this behavior.

Once you have it set up to allow duplicates, **[Create Custom Report Types for Duplicate Record Reports](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=duplicate_management_custom_report_types.htm&language=en_US)**.

> The only records that will appear in these reports are:
>
> - Records identified as duplicates by duplicates rules that include the report action.
> - Records that were manually added to the Duplicate Record Set object.
>
>   1. Make sure you’re familiar with custom report types and the general steps for creating and maintaining them.
>   2. Create custom report types with the appropriate object relationships and configure them as necessary.
>        Here are some examples of custom report types to get you started.
>
> **Report Type** Lead Duplicates
>   **Possible Use** Create reports on the duplicate leads that were found by your duplicate rules.
>   **A (Primary Object)** Leads
>   **B** Duplicate Record Items

Then your users will need to **[Subscribe to Get Report Notifications](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=reports_notifications_home.htm&siteLang=en_US)**.